# to store direct name inside document or store referenced id from master collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am having a master products collection which stores all products we manage. I have a tests collection where i store products object id in it. This way we always have to join master collection to get results. If i use master only for validation and store name of product directly in tests collection, will i get into trouble later or any kind of anomalies?

```
Products -> tests
```

I have read few documents while designing collections.
http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/schemabasics/

Comment: Some things to think about: Does the product name change? How often? I guess that having the product name in the `tests` let you _not_ do a lookup to get the name.

Comment: Product names do not change often as of now.

Comment: In such a case you can consider storing the product name in the tests also (in addition to the product). This is duplication of certain information - but it helps the application's operation. This is allowed and can be part of design.

Comment: When, the product name changes, it can be updated in both collections. Is the product name change need to be seen in all operations immediately and important ? If not the change can be applied to the test collections at the end of the day or when needed as a batch operation.

Comment: But in that case there will be no single source of truth right? just to avoid joins i am duplicating name, i shld have both product object id and name in tests of just product name?

Comment: Yes, both collection's documents has the product name (to avoid lookups). This if these lookups are often and performance is an issue.

Comment: a given product can 1..1000 tests as of now.

Comment: This is a one-to-many relationship between product and the tests. With MongoDB the model can be embedding or referencing. See [Data Model Design (embedding vs referencing)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) _and_  [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design (one-to-N relationships)](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) for some useful discussion on what suits your application needs.